# CAPL- Get value of string defined sysvar

Tags: capl, canoe, canalyzer

i defined a sysvar as a string in CANalyzer to use it with a panel.
Then in a CAPL a would like to get the value of this variable and save the name,i tried as i usually do in CAPL with the numbers so:
`write("%s",@namespace::name_of_variable)`
But i got an error saying tha the '@' should be used only for integer or float variables. How can i get the value of this string and save it in a local variable to reused it in a CAPL?
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CAPL function you are looking for is `sysGetVariableString`

Usage is as follows:

```
char value[100]; //has to be big enough to hold the value

sysGetVariableString(sysvar::namespace::name_of_variable, value, elcount(value));
```

Comment: To read a member of the struct, the `sysvarMember` shall be used instead of `sysvar`. For example: `sysvarMember::namespace::name_of_struct.name_of_member`.